# Firestore query Can't getDocuments

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

so I have an array in a collection called 'Authors'. I want to check if a certain string (mail) is there, but it says permission denied on the getDocuments.
Here's a little snippet:

```
  List<String> authors;

  _getAuthors(DocumentSnapshot doc) async {
    if (await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser() != null) {
      var query = Firestore.instance
          .collection('mealList')
          .where('Authors', arrayContains: mail);
      query.getDocuments().then((value) => print(value));
    }
  }

  Widget buildItem(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    DateTime now = doc.data['Date'].toDate();
    DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
    String formatted = formatter.format(now);
    _getUserId();
    _getMail(doc);
    if (doc.data['Authors'] != null) {
      _getAuthors(doc);
    }
```

And here's my database rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /mealList/{uid} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth == null;
    }

    match /shoppingList/{uid} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Check the security rules for mealList collection. It just blocking authorized user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   match /mealList/{uid} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth == null;
    }

should be 

   match /mealList/{uid} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
```